# How to disable row checkbox based on the cell value in Datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

How to disable row checkbox based on the cell value in Datatables. Have table and few columns have data like System. If it is system need to disbale the row. Tried below code, checkboxes are not disabled.

```
this.dtOptions = {
  ajax: 'assets/test.json',
  initComplete: function (settings, json) {
    $.each(json.data, function (index, value) {  
      if(value.matchType == "System"){ //working
        $("table").closest('tbody tr td').find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
      } 
  }); 
  },
```

Comment: In your code where you compare cell value?

Comment: In conditional statement if(value.matchType == "System")

Answer (score 1):

I your code, if index is your row index then you can try this

```
this.dtOptions = {
  ajax: 'assets/test.json',
  initComplete: function (settings, json) {
    $.each(json.data, function (index, value) {  
      if(value.matchType == "System"){ //working
        $("table tr").eq(index).find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
      } 
  }); 
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from @Yuvraj inspired me the following solution with the "createdRow" event

```
'createdRow': function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    if (!data.isAvailable /* some condition based on data */) {
        $(row).find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
    } 
}
```